# Python installing setuptools, ez_setup.py error

Tags: python, setuptools

I am trying to install setuptools on Windows.
The documentation says I should run ez_setup.py.
So I did and I get the following output:

```
Extracting in c:\users\ut601039\appdata\local\temp\tmpf6a2mb
Now working in c:\users\ut601039\appdata\local\temp\tmpf6a2mb\setuptools-1.0
Installing Setuptools
Something went wrong during the installation.
See the error message above.

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Python\Setuptools\ez_setup.py", line 357, in <module>
    sys.exit(main())
SystemExit: 2
```

The error message isn't very informative. Looking into the code I found:

```
        if not _python_cmd('setup.py', 'install', *install_args):
            log.warn('Something went wrong during the installation.')
            log.warn('See the error message above.')
            # exitcode will be 2
            return 2
```

I went to `_python_cmd()` and found:

```
def _python_cmd(*args):
args = (sys.executable,) + args
return subprocess.call(args) == 0
```

I found that `subprocess.call(args)` returns 1 instead of the expected 0.

Comment: Forget I said anything. `stdout=STDOUT` makes no sense and the behavior I wanted to achieve is the default. Sorry, I can't help.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

how are you trying to run & install it? ideally.. run cmd then cd to extracted folder & run `python setup.py install` this should install it.. if you are on 64 bit windows with 64bit python then you need to get the appropriate version can be found here: (http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#setuptools)

Comment: Yeah, I ended up installing it in a way similar to what you say. The documentation doesn't mention any of those details. Thanks.

Comment: hmm.. very well, the modules itself doesn't have it documented however **python docs** has documented on how to install python modules; which i found here: [python docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/install/index.html)